# Designate additional alias names for eslint consistent-this rule?

Tags: javascript, eslint

I recently started using the [`eslint`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint) module to help clean-up some JavaScript files. The following error is being reported when I lint one of my files:

`127:17  error  Unexpected alias 'me' for 'this'             consistent-this`

After [checking the documentation](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/consistent-this), I understand the error is being reported because my code is assigning the value of `this` to a variable named `me` instead of `that`.

What is the proper way to configure my project's `.eslintrc.json` to make it so the following line of code is not reported as an error: `var me = this;`?

Comment: As the docs explain, set `consistent-this` to `["error", "me"]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rule should be like this in your .eslintrc

```
{
   "rules" : {
       "consistent-this": ["error", "me"]
   }
}
```